# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 100" in array data structure program

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I am writing a program that creates an array with 100 random (long) elements:

**main**

```
byte maxSize = 100;
HighArray arr = new HighArray(maxSize);

for (byte j =0; j < maxSize; j++)
arr.insert((long)(Math.random()*99));
```

When I call the removeMax() method which is in the HighArray class

```
public long getMax()
    {
        long max = -1;

        for (byte i =0; i < nElems; i++)
        {
            if(max < a[i])
                max = a[i];
        }

        return max;
    }

    public long removeMax()
    {
        long max = getMax();
        delete(max);
        return max;
    }

public boolean delete(long value)
    {
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<nElems; j++)        // look for it
            if( value == a[j] )
                break;
        if(j==nElems)                  // can't find it
            return false;
        else                           // found it
        {
            for(int k=j; k<nElems; k++) // move higher ones down
                a[k] = a[k+1];
            nElems--;                   // decrement size
            return true;
        }
```

I get the array out of bounds : 100 exception. I assume this means that my array is out of bounds by 100 elements, which doesn't make sense to me since I'm deleting elements from it, not adding any. I did not get any errors when I initially created the array.

According to my IDE (Intellij IDEA), the problem happens when I call removeMax() from main.

If I am misunderstanding the error please let me know and clarify it for me. If more details or code is needed, let me know.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the exception you get?

Comment: I think you are missing some more code to add, I don't see where you are declaring: nElems and see how it behaves, please provide the whole scope and the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell with the code you have, the problem is here:

```
a[k] = a[k+1];
```

Do this instead:

```
a[k] = a[k-1];
```

You assign K the value of `J`, and when `J` is on the last iteration (100), you add 1 to it, and thus get a value of 101, which is more than the allotted 100.

Comment: That shouldn't happen since it only occurs when the condition (k < nElems) is met. Basically what this does is move all the elements of the array downward one to overwrite the element that is to be deleted. Unless I made a logical error in the code, it shouldn't have tried to access the array beyond element 99.

Comment: Hey, I just tested the code with your suggestions. You were right after all. My logic was wrong, thank you for your help. The correct way was: for(int k=j; k < nElems -1; j++) . . . .